# How to correlate the below given scenario for check boxes?

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

in my script i have a scenario like the page contains multiple check boxes for example 10, as per the user need user selects check boxes for example one user selects 4 check boxes and other user clicks 5 check boxes, so per each it will vary.

so how to correlate those values,

thanking you.

Comment: You have confused correlation and parametrization. You need to parametrize the user selection. Please consult the product help on the topic of parametrization on how to do it.

Comment: I checked, looks good. I also know Stuart, he is a great guy.

Comment: I don't know how to do it of the top of my head. I suggest you contact Stuart and ask him for a solution example.

Answer (score 0):

From the website: "Please don’t share your solutions, ask for help, or help others. This is meant to be a challenge."

So you appear to be violating one of the primary rules in this website.  I have looked at this challenge and it's really good to gauge someone's knowledge.

---

However, to address technology generally - in reading your question I get the sense you may be missing certain fundamental knowledge for this kind of thing.  Here's some fundamental knowledge.  Hopefully my answer will help increase your knowledge.  And hopefully you can use this increased general knowledge to address this specific question.

Definitions:
Correlation - you're taking data the SERVER sends to the browser, capturing it and sending it back.  Information present on web pages would fit into this category.
Parameterization - you've got a set of values you'd like to put into web forms.  This is usually values like names, addresses, etc

Also understand exactly what is happening when you conduct certain actions on your browser.  When you "click" a checkbox does that actually send a message to a server?  That usually doesn't (though not always) happen.  So when you use phrases like 'click a checkbox' that tells me you may not appreciate the fact that performance testing is server focused, not browser focused.

Performance testing isn't intuitive so you need to understand these concepts.  If you dedicate time to understanding the concepts I've outlined above you'll have the knowledge to complete the challenge.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What is driving the variation on check boxes being checked? Is it the result of something that comes back from the server, from a previous request? Or is it somewhat random based on whatever the user wants to do at runtime?